# bash stop cURL outputting to screen

Tags: bash, redirect, curl

Trying to redirect and quite the output to screen on a cURL command?  Also what happens with an exception, if cURL can't find the file on the site? Its downloading to a FTP site with an FTP URL.  I have many files so its iterating in a loop and I don't want it to stop if file isn't found so will continue if exception isn't found?  Can I use the cURL command if I am strictly using a bash script? It does download the files but it outputs to much stuff and also haven't been able to test in situation where it would throw an error so not sure if it would continue.

How can I stop cURL from outputting to screen? This is what I have so far.

```
echo $DLADDR
curl -o Downloads/$FILECATNAME $DLADDR 2>&1 | tee $LOGFILE
```

I would like to stop this output and put each output into a LOG file.

Example cURL output:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time     Time     Time      Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total    Spent    Left      Speed
100  574k  100  574k    0     0   622k       0   --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  632k
```

Comment: Consider rephrasing your question.  As is, it doesn't make it quite clear what you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, it's tough to exactly figure what you're asking.  However, one of the questions is:

> How can I stop CURL from outputting to screen?

You are saying:

```
curl -o Downloads/$FILECATNAME $DLADDR 2>&1 | tee $LOGFILE
```

which would redirect the response output to the specified file but the `STDERR` of `curl` would be merged with `STDOUT` and `tee`d to the logfile.

Redirect the output right away to *stop CURL from outputting to screen*, i.e. say:

```
curl -o Downloads/$FILECATNAME $DLADDR > $LOGFILE 2>&1
```

---

The other question appears to be:

> I don't want it to stop if file isn't found so will continue if
>   exception isn't found?

The script shouldn't stop if `curl` encounters an error unless you've specified to do so, i.e. unless you've said:

```
set -e
```

in your script.

Comment: I updated my answer.  So your second "curl -o Downloads/$FILECATNAME $DLADDR > $LOGFILE 2>&1"  does stop if from outputting to screen but it does not put each output into the log file. It just did the first one. And yes I don't have set -e so it should catch it. I actually made mistake in one my URLS so I have proof that it will continue. I would like to know which one though?! I try to figure out how to do that though. Thanks for you help so far!

Comment: @MAXGEN In order to _append_ to the file, you need to use `>>` instead of `>`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to investigate curl's `-w` (`--write-out`) option, to get precisely the log information you require, and avoid the unnecessary/unreported bits.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DLADDR=ftp://example.com/somefile
LOGFILE=/path/to/downloader.log

declare -a bashopts=()

bashopts+=(-s)
bashopts+=("-o 'Downloads/$FILECATNAME'")
bashopts+=("-w '%{size_download} %{speed_download} %{time_total} %{filename_effective}'")

curl "${bashopts[@]}" "$DLADDR" > "$LOGFILE"
```

We simplify the option management by putting it into an array. Note the options:

- `-s` silences the progress meter.
- `-o` sets an output file per your example.
- `-w` writes output according to the format listed in curl's man page.

Since you're directing the output file using `-o`, the only information curl sends to *stdout* will be the log data generated by the `-w` command.

Note that the rule of thumb for quoting variables in bash is that if you're using a variable ... it should be quoted.

Answer (score -2):

```
curl -o Downloads/$DESCFILE $TEXT1 > $TEXT 2>&1
```

Comment: Consider adding a little more detail to your answer.